# Binary classification on MNIST: loss and accuracies remain costant

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, mnist, image-classification

I am trying to do binary classification on MNIST dataset. Class 0 for even numbers and class 1 for odd numbers. I am using a simplified version of VGG.
My NN has a loss and an accuracy that remain costant.
I want to say that my model, reached to over 90% of accuracy before of changing targets into binary targets, so probably there is something wrong.
Here I change the targets into binary:

```
for i in range(10):
  idx = (train_set.targets==i)
  if (i == 0) or ((i % 2) == 0): train_set.targets[idx] = 0

  else: train_set.targets[idx] = 1

for i in range(10):
  idx = (test_set.targets==i)
  if (i == 0) or ((i % 2) == 0): test_set.targets[idx] = 0

  else: test_set.targets[idx] = 1
```

This is my net:

```
class VGG16(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(VGG16, self).__init__()

        # calculate same padding:
        # (w - k + 2*p)/s + 1 = o
        # => p = (s(o-1) - w + k)/2

        self.block_1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,
                      out_channels=64,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      # (1(32-1)- 32 + 3)/2 = 1
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64,
                      out_channels=64,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2),
                         stride=(2, 2))
        )

        self.block_2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64,
                      out_channels=128,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128,
                      out_channels=128,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2),
                         stride=(2, 2))
        )
        
        self.block_3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128,
                      out_channels=256,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256,
                      out_channels=256,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256,
                      out_channels=256,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2),
                         stride=(2, 2))
        )

        self.block_4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256,
                      out_channels=512,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512,
                      out_channels=512,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512,
                      out_channels=512,
                      kernel_size=(3, 3),
                      stride=(1, 1),
                      padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2),
                         stride=(2, 2))
        )            

        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2048, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.65),
            nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.65),
            nn.Linear(4096, num_classes),
            nn.Sigmoid() 
        )

        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, torch.nn.Conv2d) or isinstance(m, torch.nn.Linear):
                nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(m.weight, mode='fan_in', nonlinearity='leaky_relu')
#                 nn.init.xavier_normal_(m.weight)
                if m.bias is not None:
                    m.bias.detach().zero_()

        # self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((7, 7))

    def forward(self, x):

        x = self.block_1(x)
        x = self.block_2(x)
        x = self.block_3(x)
        x = self.block_4(x)
        # x = self.avgpool(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x
        #logits = self.classifier(x)
        #probas = F.softmax(logits, dim=1)
        # probas = nn.Softmax(logits)
        #return probas
        # return logits
```

```
# Define an optimizier
import torch.optim as optim
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
# Define a loss 
criterion = nn.BCELoss()


def train(net, loaders, optimizer, criterion, epochs=20, dev=dev, save_param = False, model_name="valerio"):
    try:
        net = net.to(dev)
        #print(net)
        # Initialize history
        history_loss = {"train": [], "val": [], "test": []}
        history_accuracy = {"train": [], "val": [], "test": []}
        # Store the best val accuracy
        best_val_accuracy = 0

        # Process each epoch
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            # Initialize epoch variables
            sum_loss = {"train": 0, "val": 0, "test": 0}
            sum_accuracy = {"train": 0, "val": 0, "test": 0}
            # Process each split
            for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
                if split == "train":
                  net.train()
                else:
                  net.eval()
                # Process each batch
                for (input, labels) in loaders[split]:
                    # Move to CUDA
                    input = input.to(dev)
                    labels = labels.to(dev)
                    # Reset gradients
                    optimizer.zero_grad()
                    # Compute output
                    pred = net(input)
                    labels = labels.unsqueeze(1)
                    labels = labels.float()
                    loss = criterion(pred, labels)
                    # Update loss
                    sum_loss[split] += loss.item()
                    # Check parameter update
                    if split == "train":
                        # Compute gradients
                        loss.backward()
                        # Optimize
                        optimizer.step()
                    # Compute accuracy
                    _,pred_labels = pred.max(1)
                    batch_accuracy = (pred_labels == labels).sum().item()/input.size(0)
                    # Update accuracy
                    sum_accuracy[split] += batch_accuracy
            # Compute epoch loss/accuracy
            epoch_loss = {split: sum_loss[split]/len(loaders[split]) for split in ["train", "val", "test"]}
            epoch_accuracy = {split: sum_accuracy[split]/len(loaders[split]) for split in ["train", "val", "test"]}

            # Store params at the best validation accuracy
            if save_param and epoch_accuracy["val"] > best_val_accuracy:
              #torch.save(net.state_dict(), f"{net.__class__.__name__}_best_val.pth")
              torch.save(net.state_dict(), f"{model_name}_best_val.pth")
              best_val_accuracy = epoch_accuracy["val"]

            # Update history
            for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
                history_loss[split].append(epoch_loss[split])
                history_accuracy[split].append(epoch_accuracy[split])
            # Print info
            print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}:",
                  f"TrL={epoch_loss['train']:.4f},",
                  f"TrA={epoch_accuracy['train']:.4f},",
                  f"VL={epoch_loss['val']:.4f},",
                  f"VA={epoch_accuracy['val']:.4f},",
                  f"TeL={epoch_loss['test']:.4f},",
                  f"TeA={epoch_accuracy['test']:.4f},")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Interrupted")
    finally:
        # Plot loss
        plt.title("Loss")
        for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
            plt.plot(history_loss[split], label=split)
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
        # Plot accuracy
        plt.title("Accuracy")
        for split in ["train", "val", "test"]:
            plt.plot(history_accuracy[split], label=split)
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
```

From the previous model of digit recognition i changed only the targets, and the final layer of classifier from 10 classes to 1 class + Sigmoid. And i changed also cross entropy to BCELoss. What I am doing wrong?

These are loss and accuracy values:

```
Epoch 1: TrL=49.0955, TrA=31.4211, VL=49.7285, VA=31.7340, TeL=49.2635, TeA=31.3758,
Epoch 2: TrL=49.0992, TrA=31.4235, VL=49.7285, VA=31.7340, TeL=49.2635, TeA=31.3758,
Epoch 3: TrL=49.0899, TrA=31.4176, VL=49.7285, VA=31.7340, TeL=49.2635, TeA=31.3758,
Epoch 4: TrL=49.0936, TrA=31.4199, VL=49.7285, VA=31.7340, TeL=49.2635, TeA=31.3758,
Epoch 5: TrL=49.0936, TrA=31.4199, VL=49.7285, VA=31.7340, TeL=49.2635, TeA=31.3758,
Epoch 6: TrL=49.0825, TrA=31.4128, VL=49.7285, VA=31.7340, TeL=49.2635, TeA=31.3758,
```

What's wrong? How is it possible that with 10 classes I reached over 90% accuracy, and with a simplified version, only 2 classes, I reach 30% of accuracy?

Edit: increasing batch size from 64 to 128, accuracy reaches to 60% and remains constant...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the problem is different representations of odd and even numbers. Let's take 1, 3 pictures with this number are sundry, and convolution neural networks have a problem with extract features. The neural network has 90% accuracy, with 10 classes, so why you need to convert this into 2. If you know that number is 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, you know that it's odd.

Comment: Because I am doing a project of transfer learning, and I want to have 2 NN that do binary classification for simpliticy. And both of them I want at least 70% of accuracy. MNIST is 60000 samples, doing binary classification on this dataset I think that is simplier than doing multiclass classification.

Comment: Mostly there is simpler to learn binary classification, but in this problem, you have 5 different types of pictures in 1 class. i.e. if you have dogs and cats, binary classification is simpler than multiclassification for their breeds because cats and dogs are more similar (ears, muzzle). A basic neural network has high accuracy in this set of data. So if the more complex network has lower that I think the problem is in only 2 classes.